# Ordenando Com determinada condição

Tags: c, classificação, complexidade-de-algoritmo, quicksort

Fiz a questão [Quem Vai Ser Reprovado?](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2134) que tinha a regra Os alunos seriam ordenados conforme o número de problemas resolvidos, com empates resolvidos de acordo com a ordem alfabética dos nomes (não há homônimos na turma), Bom eu consegui resolver só que queria outra maneira por que nesse precisei ordenar duas vezes
Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pessoas
{
 char nome[100];
 int nota;

};

struct pessoas pessoa[102];
void ordena(int teste);
void ordena2(int teste);

int main()
{
  int teste, i, cont = 0;
  while(scanf("%d", &teste) == 1)
  {
      for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
      {
         scanf("%s %d", pessoa[i].nome, &pessoa[i].nota);
      }

      ordena(teste);
      ordena2(teste);
      printf("Instancia %d\n", ++cont);
      puts(pessoa[teste - 1].nome);
      putchar('\n');
  }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

void ordena(int teste)
{
  int i, j , aux;
  char a[100];
  for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
  {
     for(j = 0; j < teste; j++)
     {
         if(pessoa[i].nota > pessoa[j].nota)
         {
             aux = pessoa[i].nota;
             pessoa[i].nota = pessoa[j].nota;
             pessoa[j].nota = aux;
             strcpy(a, pessoa[i].nome);
             strcpy(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome);
             strcpy(pessoa[j].nome, a);
         }
     }
 }
}

 void ordena2(int teste)
 {
    int i, j, aux;
    char a[100];
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < teste; j++)
        {
           if(pessoa[i].nota == pessoa[j].nota)
           {
              if(strcmp(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome) > 0)
              {
                strcpy(a, pessoa[i].nome);
                strcpy(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome);
                strcpy(pessoa[j].nome, a);
                aux = pessoa[i].nota;
                pessoa[i].nota = pessoa[j].nota;
                pessoa[j].nota = aux;
              }
           }
       }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Não percebi muito bem, quer outras formas de ordenar? Como por exemplo QuickSort?

Comment: Poderia ser, o problema que não consigo ordenar com as regras como a questão pede

Comment: Não estou percebendo bem, mas em vez de fazer as funçoes separadas pode as juntar

Comment: Teria uma forma mais resumida de se fazer isso, por que tem vários if e deixa o tempo mais lento

Comment: Claro que sim, mas isso tem de ver outro metodos, o seu metodo de ordenaçao é O(N^2), vou referenciar na minha resposta outras metodos de ordenaçao

Answer (score 1):

```
     if(pessoa[i].nota > pessoa[j].nota)
     {
         aux = pessoa[i].nota;
         pessoa[i].nota = pessoa[j].nota;
         pessoa[j].nota = aux;
         strcpy(a, pessoa[i].nome);
         strcpy(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome);
         strcpy(pessoa[j].nome, a);
     }
     else
        if(pessoa[i].nota == pessoa[j].nota)
       {
          if(strcmp(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome) > 0)
          {
            strcpy(a, pessoa[i].nome);
            strcpy(pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[j].nome);
            strcpy(pessoa[j].nome, a);
            aux = pessoa[i].nota;
            pessoa[i].nota = pessoa[j].nota;
            pessoa[j].nota = aux;
          }
       }
```

Dessa forma ia ver primeiro se a nota do `i` era maior que o do `j`, caso fosse igual passava para aquela condição.

O seu metodo de ordenação é o [selection sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) que tem complexidade de N^2, um dos metodos mais rapidos, mas um pouco dificel é o [quick sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) que tem complexidade no melhor caso de Nlog(N).
O [insertion sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) já é um pouco mais facil que o QuickSort e tem complexidade de N no melhor caso.

Pode ver esses metodos de forma intuitiva no site [VisuAlgo](https://visualgo.net/en)

Estar a dar um código pronto do QuickSort para o seu codigo é bastante trabalhoso e por isso indicava que você tentasse fazer por si mesmo.

[METODOS DE ORDENAÇÃO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)